# How do I solve an inequality with 2 inverse trigonometrical functions involved?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry, inequality

I haven't worked with this in a long time! All I remember is that increasing vs decreasing functions have the power of modifying the symbol.

$$\arcsin\left(\dfrac{2}{x}\right) > \arccos\left(\dfrac{2}{x}\right)$$

If I take the sin of the arcsin I will have $\dfrac{2}{x}$, I am very confused on how to approach this, can you give me some insight, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use $\arccos(y)=\dfrac\pi2-\arcsin(y)$ to get $$2\arcsin\dfrac2x>\frac\pi2\iff\arcsin\dfrac2x>\dfrac\pi4$$

As $\arcsin$ is increasing, we need $\dfrac2x>\sin\dfrac\pi4=\dfrac1{\sqrt2}$

Answer (score 1):

Take sin of both sides, then use the fact that $$\sin \cos^{-1} x=\sqrt{1-x^2}$$