# Trigonometric inequation $\sin^{-1} \frac 2x > \cos^{-1} \frac 2x$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

So I have this trigonometric inequality (and I need to solve for $x$):
$$\sin^{-1} \frac 2x > \cos^{-1} \frac 2x.$$
If I apply sine and cosine to both sides of the equation, I get
$$\cos \frac 2x > \sin \frac 2x.$$

> Can I do that? Also, if I can, in fact, do it, then what should be done in order to proceed?

Also, the answer I *should* be getting is the range $[2, 2\sqrt {2}]\,\,.$

Comment: "If I aply sine and cosine to both sides of the equation, I get" - that's wrong, you can't apply different functions do the sides of inequation with guaranteed keeping of the sign.

Comment: @Vegetable, See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1141555/how-do-i-solve-an-inequality-with-2-inverse-trigonometrical-functions-involved/1141638#1141638

Answer (score 1):

You cannot take the sine of one side and the cosine of the other - you need to apply the same operation on both sides to maintain the inequality.

Note that $\sin^{-1}\frac{2}{x}=\cos^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{x^2-4}}{x}$, so that your inequality is
$$\cos^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{x^2-4}}{x}>\cos^{-1}\frac{2}{x}$$
Now take the cosine of both sides.

Answer (score 1):

look at the unit circle with the point $P = (x,y)$ and $Q = (y,x)$ where we limit $1/\sqrt 2 \le x \le 1$ and $0 \le y \le 1/\sqrt 2.$  the point $P$ is on the unit circle between the $x$-axis and the diagonal line $y = x.$ call the point $A = (1,0), Q$ is the image of $P$ on the mirror $y = x.$

by definition $$\sin^{-1} y = arc(AP) \le arc(AQ) = \cos^{-1}y \text{ for } 1/\sqrt 2 \le y \le 1. $$

put $x = \dfrac{1}{y}$ to get the inequality you want.

Answer (score 0):

$$sin^{-1} \frac 2x > cos^{-1} \frac 2x => sin^{-1} \frac 2x >\frac\pi4$$
Now looking at the graph of sine inverse, we get $$ \frac 1{\sqrt {2}} < \frac 2x < 1 => 2 < x < 2\sqrt {2}$$